# Is it possible to have a dynamic payload value in a Messenger button?

Tags: node.js, payload, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm struggling with a payload issue on a Facebook messenger bot.
How to pass a parameter in the payload. I simply want to stock an info before launching a webview on a button.
But my postback can't interpret the dynamic payload.
I read that some people are using m.me links with parameters but i sounds weird that you can't pass parameters with m.me links.
Any idea.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you asking how to pass a parameter when the user clicks an m.me link?

Comment: Actually I would like to rely on the payload/ postback.
I would like to have payload such as "find-xxx" but I don't want to have a xxx versions of the postback.
I found strange that the button element does not allow a data element. 
i've seen indeed that people rely on m.me links but it soinds strange to me to rely on this scheme. But maybe i'm wrong ;-)

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're getting at. You can set the payload of the button dynamically when you define the button, but the payload only accepts a string, and it sounds like you want to send something more like a JSON object (assuming that's what you mean by data element)?  If that's the case, you can always stringify the object to set the payload, then parse it when the payload is received.

Comment: Yes exactly. but how to parse rhe payload value before the postback is called. Is it possible ? Usuy I define the payload and track this value with postback.

Comment: And what about stocking the param data in a global variable linked tonthe userID accessible on the code after the postback detection ?

Comment: Maybe a better solution for you would be to cache the data server-side using the `psid` or `mid` as the key?

Comment: It works with the parsing . Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Putting this answer from comment thread here if anyone needs it:

You can set the payload of the button dynamically when you define the button, but the payload only accepts a string, so you can stringify the object to set the payload, then parse it when the payload is received.